# What happens if you try to insert two same objects with different hashcode in hashmap?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, hashmap, theory

What happens if you try to insert two same objects with different hashcode in hashmap?

Comment: if they have different hashcodes then they are by all intents and purposes different as far as the hashmap is concerned.

Comment: Two objects for which the function equals (or equivalent) used by the hashmap yields true, but that have different hashcodes: If this situation is allowed or not or how it is handled I think I depends on the language/implementation.

Comment: Simple answer: they'd get inserted. Oh yes, there'll be duplicates. But how two identical objects get different hashcodes is very puzzling. Doesn't that mean the hashing function is erroneous?

Answer (score 2):

It means that a hash function is broken(at least, from hash table's perspective), so it can behave in an unpredictable manner(it is possible that a duplicate will be inserted).

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a simple implementation of a hashed map to store key-value pairs.
Suppose there is an allocated storage area of size allocated_size for keys and same for values.
The storage index for storing a new pair is computed with a simple modulo like `hash_index = (hash_code(key) % allocated_size)`.
If the slot at this hash_index is free, we're done, we just store the key and value at this index.
If the slot at this hash_index is already occupied, then it depends:

- if the key at this slot is equal, then we're done, we found the `hash_index`, and we will overwrite the associated value;
- if the key at this slot is different, then we have to scan storage at `hash_index+1`, until we find an equal key, or an empty slot.

Now, suppose we have hash_codes 33 and 53 for two equal keys.

- If allocated_size is 20, then the two hash_codes are equal modulo 20, and we will store a single object (the second insertion will overwrite the first one);
- If allocated_size is 21, then the two hash_codes are different modulo 21, and we might store two occurences of this key, each with their own value, depending on occupation of slots in between the two hash_index, and depending on the order of insertion of the pairs...

What you observe here is typical **undefined behavior**. I'm pretty sure more ellaborate implementations will suffer from equivalent problems, so no, two equal keys **SHALL NOT** have a different hash code, it's a broken hash function.